# Configure ValueGenerator for autoincrement decimal field in InMemoryProvider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

### Problem

In my app, I use SQL Server:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

but when I use InMemoryProvider in my unit tests:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    Services = new ServiceCollection();
    Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyDbContext"), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    ServiceProvider = Services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

I'm getting:

> System.NotSupportedException: The 'PersonId' on entity type 'Person' does not have a value set and no value generator is available for properties of type 'decimal'. Either set a value for the property before adding the entity or configure a value generator for properties of type 'decimal'.

### Question

Where do I configure custom ValueGenerator for PersonId property, so that it will be used only in my test project where I use InMemoryProvider?

### What I have

I have MS SQL Server Database and a table with autoincrement identity column of type numeric(10, 0).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People](
    [Person ID] [numeric](10, 0) IDENTITY(100000000,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_People] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

and the EF Code

```
[Column("Person ID", TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")]
public decimal PersonId { get; set; }

public class MyDbContext
{
    public OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
        {
           entity.Property(e => e.PersonId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });
    }
}
```

My application uses SQL Server, but I want to setup EF to use InMemoryProvider in tests. The Custom ValueGenerator should be used only in tests

Comment: What's the target EFC version?

Comment: EF Version is Core 2.0

Comment: Ok, it's reproducible, but is there any reason of using `decimal` and not `int` which is working?

Comment: I'm using DB First. How can I map numeric fields to ulong? numeric maps to decimal. I don't like it either, but do I have the choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of EFC 2.0, the In-Memory Database Provider supports value generation only for integer types - `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long` and `ulong`.

So one way to resolve the issue is to map the PK property to some of these types which fits in the desired range, like `int`, `long` etc.

But if you insist using `decimal`, then you can use the following fluent setup:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.Internal;

// ...

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
{
    var pb = entity.Property(e => e.PersonId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    if (Database.IsInMemory())
        pb.HasValueGenerator<InMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<decimal>>();
});
```

or if you have more properties like this, you could keep the existing configuration and add the following at the end of your `OnModelCreating` override:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.Internal;

// ...

if (Database.IsInMemory())
{
    var autoGenDecimalProperies = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .Select(t => t.FindPrimaryKey())
        .Where(pk => pk != null)
        .SelectMany(pk => pk.Properties)
        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) && p.ValueGenerated != ValueGenerated.Never);

    foreach (var property in autoGenDecimalProperies)
        property.SetValueGeneratorFactory((p, t) => new InMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<decimal>());
}
```